# Strange Scala Error when Using Scala Reflect

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I added a dependency to the scala reflect library version 2.11.8 to one of my existing project such that I could use TypeTag's but strangely I face some error when running. Here is my error:

```
Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10a3ab4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10b4ce4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/my/csvparser/CSVParser$.scala$App$_setter_$executionStart_$eq(J)V is abstract
    at com.my.csvparser.CSVParser$.scala$App$_setter_$executionStart_$eq(CSVParser.scala)
    at scala.App$class.$init$(App.scala:44)
    at com.my.csvparser.CSVParser$.<init>(CSVParser.scala:13)
    at com.my.csvparser.CSVParser$.<clinit>(CSVParser.scala)
    at com.my.csvparser.CSVParser.main(CSVParser.scala)
```

Did anyone face a similar issue? My Scala version is 2.11.8

Comment: well... looks like a problem of JAVA_HOME ??

Comment: Can't be! This happens only if I add scala reflect as my dependency!

Comment: @sparkr, Do you have a small reprodicible example aka [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I can link it to my GitHub repo: Here it is: https://github.com/joesan/csv-parser

Comment: @sparkr, Sorry but that code doesn't compile, and if I fix `Dependencies.scala`, it doesn't run (even when I fix path to `address.csv`). This is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Strange! Let me take a look! I will post back!

Comment: Ok! Have a look now! It compiles. But you know the whole point behind this post is to fix the compile error and which was why I comited to my GitHub that was failing compilation. But you have it now, a version that compiles and runs! Take a look!

Comment: @sparkr, First, the question is about runtime error rather than compilation error, isn't it? Secondly, you still didn't address the main issue: your code points to `address.csv` in you home folder and  if I change it to the one in the GitHub I still get error "_unable to parse line List(joe,san,1) << reason >> Expected more fields_" rather than what you describe in your question. How we are supposed to fix an error that is not reproducible?

Comment: unable to parse line List(joe,san,1) << reason >> Expected more fields is the result of parsing the csv file. It could be that the CSV file is not in an expected format. If you take a look, there is a line that is commented (line 84 and 85) in the CSVParser.scala. If you uncomment this line, you will see that it parses successfully. But in line 87, I'm trying to parse the CSV with a Pipe seperator which is why you see the error!

Comment: So the whole point was to be able to recognize such errors in advance and give the result back

Comment: If you now add the dependency to the scala reflect, you should get the error as I mentioned in my post above!

Comment: SergGr: Did you attempt to try out and reproduce the issue?

Comment: Have you figured out why it happens ?

Comment: Unfortunately no!

Comment: Did you get the hit on this issue I am too facing this issue @joesan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me by removing object class extending App and putting all piece of code into main method means doing

```
object Test {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  }
}
```

Instead of

```
object Test extends App {
       
    }
```

I am still not sure why it just worked as I am also new to scala world.